# How can I find out, from within a .bat- (or .ps1-) script, if it was started by the task scheduler?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I'm actually interested as the question is stated, but what I'm after is a mechanism for temporarily disable the scheduled run (on multiple servers, whith shared disk), while still being able to run it interactively (if the script can be made to tell if it's started from task-scheduler or not). An external flag (the existence of a file) seemed like a simple approach to do that.

First option was using "%SESSIONNAME%" which seems to be empty when started from the scheduler, although that's also the case when started from powershell (with Start-Process, which might be an option for allowed usage while disabled).

EDIT: A second option, using the `whoami` cmd-command seems more promising, it reports the user as belonging to the group **NT AUTHORITY\BATCH** when run from task scheduler (but not when run interactively). Could I shoot myself in the foot using this - can a user be added to that group "permanently" behind my back?

We're on Windows Server 2012 R2. PowerShell solution would be interesting, as a wrapper could probably be used (or even modification/rewrite from .bat to .ps1).

Comment: Make the scheduled version pass a `/sched` command line to the bat?

Comment: Thanks, you mean like a command line argument? Almost a cheat ;-)

Comment: Sure, seems like an acceptable approach to me

Comment: Sure (and thanks), I might well do that, but I'd rather have that logic "hidden" in the script. If it's reasonably doable, it might come in handy for other scripts.

Comment: The .Net class [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity] has some interesting properties. `[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name` 
will give me the user account, which, in this case, will be (or can be made to) a specific account. Still cheating, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @Alex K.: passing a separate argument to signal that we're running in a scheduled context works fine. Simple, reliable techniques that don't require you to know anything about third-party components -- in my neck of the woods we call those "wins" rather than "cheats".

If you really want, you can check for what you're literally asking -- if we're running from Task Scheduler -- by checking the properties of our parent process. From PowerShell this is quite doable, don't know about plain old batch files:

```posh
$parentpid = (gwmi "win32_process where (ProcessId = $pid)").parentprocessid
$parentname = (gwmi "win32_process where (ProcessId = $parentpid)").name
if ($parentname -eq 'taskeng.exe') {
    "I think this is Task Scheduler, or maybe something else a hacker named taskeng.exe, who knows?"
} else {
    "This is not Task Scheduler. Probably."
}
```

Of course, this might break if one day MS renames the process, or indeed if you want to use something else than TS to run the script automatically, or even if the script invokes another process which in turn invokes a script.

Personally, I would definitely go with the explicit flag. If you forget to apply it, it will be obvious, it can't suddenly break one day, and best of all, you can test if your script works correctly without actually having to schedule it first.

Comment: Great! I totally agree about wins/cheats - it was a cheat only as an answer to the question, not as a reliable way to solve the problem.

Comment: **Archival note:** this method unfortunately doesn't get 'taskeng.exe' as the parent, but 'svchost.exe', which is probably even less useful than taskeng. However, it does differentiate a user-invoked run from a scheduled one. (thanks @Jeroen, for the problem at hand I'll stick with the "separate argument"-approach, though this "inspect call-stack" is what I wanted to learn.)

Comment: @perostb: I tested this on Windows 7 with a user-scheduled task, where the parent process is "taskeng.exe". But, as I mentioned, this is quite brittle because there is certainly no guarantee this is the case.